# Admob requires api-13 or later can I not deploy on old API-8 phones?

Tags: android, admob

Google Admob requires that I have to compile my project with API-13 or later. To be able to use admob sdk.
My application is meant for mobiles with api-8 or later.

Does it mean if I compile my app with Api-13 or later I have to abandon my app support for older phones before Api-13 ?

My understanding is that since admob requires minimum api-13 to compile , it means it calls functions which are not available on old phones, so I am confused that potentially It won't be able to run my app for Api-8  to Api-12 and probably crash ?

Please advise me on this,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean if I compile my app with Api-13 or later I have to abandon my app support for older phones before Api-13 ?

No. If you read [the AdMob documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals), "The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires a run-time of Android 1.5 or later (set android:minSdkVersion to at least 3 in your AndroidManifest.xml). This means you can develop with the latest version of the Android SDK and your app will still run on an earlier Android version (1.5 minimum)."

> My understanding is that since admob requires minimum api-13 to compile , it means it calls functions which are not available on old phones

It *conditionally* "calls function which are not available on old phones". This is fairly commonplace in Android development -- you use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to determine if you are on a newer device and do one thing with newer APIs, but do something else on older devices.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, do I need to do through testing of my app if I just change compilation from api-8 to api-13 or later or does android theoretically makes a promise it won't break at runtime (given I don't change code to call higher api's).

Comment: @Ahmed: "does android theoretically makes a promise it won't break at runtime (given I don't change code to call higher api's)" -- well, there are few guarantees in life. :-) That being said, if you stick to older methods, it will run on older devices. Set your `android:minSdkVersion` to the oldest version you wish to support (`8`, apparently), and the dev tools' Lint facility will help let you know about places where you are using things only available in newer API levels than what your `minSdkVersion` calls for.

Comment: I understand there is no guarantee but I wanted to grasp it conceptually , thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

in the android manifest i left the mini sdk as 8  .  I then used ADT .. right click on project went to properties and set the target API to 13.  tested on both devices with different API, works.