# Minimum Android API level Required for AdMob?

Tags: android, api

When i was implementing the demo banner ad example in my android phone API-16;
i was getting two errors:-

1. could not find class 'android.os.usermanager'
2. could not find class 'android.app.appopsmanager'

the former requires API level 17 and above while the later requires API level 19 and above. 
but [Admob requires api-13 or later can I not deploy on old API-8 phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353784/admob-requires-api-13-or-later-can-i-not-deploy-on-old-api-8-phones--------)
shows that the minimum API level for AdMob is 13..
**What exactly is the Minimum API level for AdMob required???**

Answer (score 0):

A minimum API level is 9(Android 2.3)

Please check Admob document [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#prerequisites)

You can also check Get started.

Comment: What is the minimum API level for Google Analytics?

Comment: It's also Android 2.3. check [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)